# Can I make a collection append-only in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore, database-security

I want to write game events and audit logs from my app to Cloud Firestore. Once written, I don't want the user to be able to modify or delete these events/logs.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Rules in Cloud Firestore makes it quite simply to make a collection, or even the entire database, into an append-only system from the mobile & web clients.

## Example

Below is a set of rules that will turn the root collection `audit_logs` into an append-only collection.

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents/ {
      function permission_granted() {
         return request.auth != null; // Change this to your logic.
      }

      match /audit_logs/{log} {
         allow update,delete: if false;
         allow read, create, list: if permission_granted();
      }
   }
}
```

Let's break down the most important pieces.

### Function: permission_granted()

```
function permission_granted() {
   return request.auth != null; // Change this to your logic.
}
```

This one is just a placeholder for however you want to restrict insert new documents or reading existing documents in the collection. In this case it's letting anyone who has signed in using Firebase Auth -> You might want it more restrictive.

It just returns `true` or `false`, which we'll use later to actually enforce.

### Match: Root collection audit_log

match /audit_logs/{log} {
   ...
}

This one's simple, we're just matching against any requests regarding for the root collect called `audit_logs`. The document Id in questions is made available via `$(log)` due to the `{log}` piece.

### Blocking any modification that is append-only

```
allow update,delete: if false;
```

The 2 write methods that are not append-only are `update` and `delete`, so here we just universally disallow any mobile & web SDK from performing them.

### Allow the rest

```
allow read, create, list: if permission_granted();
```

Lastly, using the `permission_granted` function we set up earlier, we allow reading, listing, and creating new documents in the collection.